# What is BaseMosaic (NVidia/X11)

Tags: gpu, x11, nvidia, xorg

I see references to BaseMosaic in the NVidia X Server Settings applet, and in my xorg.conf, but I can't find a good description of it.   What is it, and what does it do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mosaic is the way nvidia handles multiple GPUs and monitors.

BaseMosaic is when using separate GPUs without SLI, as there is also SLI Mosaic.

See [Mosaic and SLI Mosaic](http://nvidia.helpmax.net/en/workstation/mosaic-and-sli-mosaic/reference/mosaic-and-sli-mosaic-mode/) for more detailed information